# what is the problem in my file handling program?

Tags: c++, file-handling

I have written the following code

```
switch (number) {
  case 1:
    int accountnumber[20];
    char firstname[20], lastname[20], balance[20];
    cout << "please enter the account number of the user " << endl;
    cin.getline(accountnumber, 20);
    cout << "please enter the first name of the user " << endl;
    cin.getline(firstname, 20);
    cout << "please enter the last name of the user " << endl;
    cin.getline(lastname, 20);
    cout << "please enter the balance of the user " << endl;
    cin.getline(balance, 20);
    ofstream myfile(" data.txt");
    myfile << accountnumber;
    myfile.close();
    int accountnumber1[20];
    ifstrean.obj("data.txt");
    obj.getline(accountnumber1, 20);
    cout << "data is" << accountnumber1;
    obj.close();
}
```

It is showing the following errors

```
no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream<char>::getline(int[20], int) '
expected unqualified-id before'.' token
```

What are the mistakes that I am doing?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is "accountnumber[20]" on line 4 is an integer array and you pass it to cin.getline on line 10, when it expects a char array instead. Since you're using a char array for numeric values such as balance, you might wanna consider making your account number into a char array as well.

```
int accountnumber[20];
char firstname[20], 
lastname[20], balance[20];
```

becomes

```
char accountnumber[20], firstname[20], lastname[20], balance[20];
```

The formatting on your code is also really unconventional, you might want to stick to something more common for making it easier for anyone to read it.

Comment: Well, the formatting is not only unconventional, I'm afraid it simply makes the code syntactically invalid.

Comment: Or maybe use a `int` for balance instead of any array.

Comment: I would certainly use a numeric type for the balance, but as for the account number it would depend, in some identifiers the leading zeros are valid and a numeric type would simply omit those, and an int would be incapable of holding 20 numeric digits on most systems.